# Final callback not showing any result

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am using async series to run 2 functions `takes2Seconds` and function `takes5Seconds`.Why the final callback not showing any result?

```
var async = require('async'),
operations = [];

operations.push(takes2Seconds(1,function(){}));
operations.push(takes5seconds(2,function(){}));

async.series(operations, function (err, results) {
 if(err){return err;}
 console.log(results);
});



function takes2Seconds(a,callback) {

    results='Took 2 sec'+a;
    callback(null, results);
}

function takes5seconds(b,callback) {
    results='Took 5sec'+b;
    callback(null, results);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are `push`ing two undefined values to `operations`.

When running `async.series` the `operations` array needs to contain function(s) that has `callback` as it's parameter.

When you do `operations.push(takes2Seconds(1, function() {}));` you are invoking the `takes2Seconds` function straight away, and because there is no `return` statement in the `takes2Seconds` function, it is `push`ing `undefined` to the operations array.

Below, I have added a `return` statement into your takesXSeconds functions. They now return a function with `callback` as the parameter, and the returned function gets pushed to the `operations` array.

I have also remove the `callback` param from takesXSeconds as it is not needed at this point.

When running `async.series(...)` now, each function (which we returned from takesXSeconds) gets invoked.

```
var async = require('async'),
    operations = [];

operations.push(takes2Seconds(1));
operations.push(takes5seconds(2));

async.series(operations, function (err, results) {
 if(err){return err;}
 console.log(results);
});

function takes2Seconds(a) {
    var results='Took 2 sec'+a;

    return function(callback) {
      callback(null, results);
    }
}

function takes5seconds(b) {
    var results='Took 5sec'+b;

    return function(callback) {
      callback(null, results);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please give a elaborate explanation

Comment: @aryankanwar I have added an explanation. Hopefully this explains. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: when I write callback(null,result) isnt that enough for returning?Why have you made a returninf function and passed callback as its argument and then finally called the callback inside it?

Comment: you need to provide callback as the first parameter as per the `async` documentation. I have provided another example in my answer. When async.series runs, it passes a function to your takesXSeconds functions, hence the need for `callback` param.

Comment: but i need to pass parameter also

Comment: Ok, then we need to use my first example. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First your takes2Seconds function executed then  function takes5seconds executed.

```
 var takes2Seconds = function (a, callback) {//first this function executed
        results = 'Took 2 sec' + a;
        callback(null, results);
    };
    async.eachSeries(takes2Seconds, takes5seconds, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({status: 0, msg: "OOPS! How is this possible?"});
        }
        res.json("Series Processing Done");
    })
    var takes5seconds = function (b, callback) { // second this function executed
        results = 'Took 5sec' + b;
        callback(null, results);
    }
```